# Get ID in callback on .create([data],cb) in Loopback

Tags: javascript, loopback

I create a model instance:

```
    Rental.create({
        user: 'john',
        period: 4
    }, (err, rental) => {
        // is it possible to get rental id here?
    });
```

The returned instance in the callback contains all I need but ID, which I need to perform other actions where I need it to be inserted into another entity.

How is it supposed to work when I need to create a new model instance and use its ID to do something else?

Comment: Is `Rental` a mongoose model? or what?

Comment: It's a Loopback model

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the property `idInjection": true` in your Rental JSON?

This enables the ID prop on the create method:

```
{
    "name": "Rental",
    "plural": "rental",
    "base": "PersistedModel",
    "strict": true,
    "idInjection": true,
```